# How can I find out the XPath if getting the 3 same Weblocators

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

WebElements in HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:procWirelineSubscribe()" class="frg-button color-green">Order</a>
<a href="javascript:procWirelineSubscribe()" class="frg-button color-green">Order</a>
<a href="javascript:procWirelineSubscribe()" class="frg-button color-green">Order</a>
```

Xpath I'm using:

```
//*[contains(@href,'javascript:procWirelineSubscribe()')]
```

However, it will always result up in ending 3 weblocators and because of this my script getting failed with

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Can someone help here me please?

Comment: Can you provide the html you're trying this on?

Comment: I had already provided the HTML in my query..

Answer (score 0):

'NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:' means the element is not found. If it would result in 3 weblocators, it would click the first element it could find.

It may be because of parsing errors. Try using only a part of the href like this:

```
//*[contains(@href,'procWirelineSubscribe')]
```

Comment: Not working,showing 6 result

Answer (score 0):

To reduce your three matches to one, try adding a `[1]` to the end of your expression. This error may occur because the result is a list instead of an item.

```
//*[contains(@href,'javascript:procWirelineSubscribe()')][1]
```

Then only one of the three (seemingly identical) elements will be selected.